# Trouble using ls() function inside substr() function

Tags: r, substring, substr

I am in need of a list or vector of all object names with the last character trimmed off.
For example:

```
# if i have two objects (ob1 and other1)
ls()
##"ob1" "other1" 
# I want "ob" "other"
```

I am attempting to use `substr()` in a loop with `ls()`, but am getting a vector of empty characters ( "" ). Ignoring the loop for now, what do I have to do to get `ls()[1]` to be treated properly inside `substr()`?

```
ob1 <– NULL
substr(ls()[1],1,length(ls()[1])-1)
##[1] ""

substr(paste(ls()[1]),1,length(ls()[1])-1)
##[1] ""

substr(toString(ls()[1]),1,length(ls()[1])-1)
##[1] ""

substr(as.character(ls()[1]),1,length(ls()[1])-1)
##[1] ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `length()` instead of `nchar()`. Change that and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use sub function to remove the last character from a string.

```
> x <- c("ob1", "other1")
> sub(".$", "", x)
[1] "ob"    "other"
```

Comment: for the last 2, you could use `sub(".{2}$", "", x)` likewise increase the number present inside the curly brace to remove no of chars from the last. And i think you need to use `ls()` instead of `x` in the above code.